# How to solve error “SyntaxError: Unexpected token” and “npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE”

Tags: npm, webpack

I receive the following error when I run `npm start`. Could anyone please help me with this issue. I encounter it only on Windows 10; everything works fine on macOS.

Here is the traceback:

```
$ npm start

> webpack-boilerplate@1.0.0 start E:\Projects\Upwork_Projects\wellness-osteo\markup
> webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js

E:\Projects\Upwork_Projects\wellness-osteo\markup\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\node_modules\p-limit\index.js:30
                } catch {}
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\Upwork_Projects\wellness-osteo\markup\node_modules\copy-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:12:38)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack-boilerplate@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-boilerplate@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\krish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-08T17_46_12_163Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the catch statement is missing an exception variable

it should have been written as

```
} catch (e) { }
```

This has been resolved as of `copy-webpack-plugin^@6.3.0`

Try upgrading / downgrading to an earlier version to resolve this.

c.f try/catch block in the [Javascript MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)